# Bash default command line editing mode

Tags: command-line, bash, readline

What is the default command line editing mode for bash?

I have been playing around with the command line editing modes in bash.The problem is that i have added lines in bashrc to toggle the vi and emacs mode as per this link.
[Toggle bash editing mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2640141/is-there-a-way-to-switch-bash-or-zsh-from-emacs-mode-to-vi-mode-with-a-keystroke)

```
set -o vi
bind '"\ee": emacs-editing-mode'
set -o emacs
bind '"\ee": vi-editing-mode'
```

According to the order, the mode set in my bash shell would be emacs mode. And it is. It works fine, except that now, my home,end keys translate to tilde symbols. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

The [default mode is Emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Line-Editing), but after your snippet, it stays in Vi mode. Append another `set -o emacs` to change it.

Regardless of that, my Home and End keys still work. The tildes you get appear to have a different cause.

Comment: I am sorry, i put the order wrong in the question.Edited it now.